# Hide HTML with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html written on a page like this that I can not control and I can only get access to it using jquery, which I need your help to solve.

```
<span class="breadcrumb">
<a href="http://www.example.com" class="breadcrumb"></a>Home / 
<a href="http://www.example.com" class="breadcrumb">Home</a> / 
</span>
```

I would like to hide only the "Home /" text from the first line that has the empty link. This issue is the text is not wrapped in the link, but is plain text.

But I want to keep the second line visible that contains the link

```
<a href="http://www.example2.com" class="breadcrumb">Home</a> /
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the [.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).. then use [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to get the text portion that you don't want

```
$('span.breadcrumb').contents().slice(2,3).remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3gpgY/

if you want to remove the anchor before the text too, just change the starting index

```
$('span.breadcrumb').contents().slice(1,3).remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eK7F7/

Comment: beautiful. that's what i needed

$('span.breadcrumb').contents().slice(1,2).remove();

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".breadcrumb a:nth-child(2)").prevAll().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following :

```
var content = $('.breadcrumb a').eq(1);
$('.breadcrumb').eq(0).html(content);
```

You can see the result here : http://codepen.io/joe/pen/uoeIh

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dirty solution

```
 $( '.breadcrumb' ).html( $( '.breadcrumb' ).html().replace( /[^\n]*><\/a>[^\n]*\n/, '' ) );
```

if you want to do it with the DOM nodes you've to use `$.( '.breadcrumb' ).contents()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var newCont = $('<span>')
    $('.breadcrumb a').each(function (){
        $(newCont).append($(this).html())
    })
    $('.breadcrumb').html(newCont)
})​
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hA6gf/2/